# CakePHP - Sorting using HABTM Join Table Field

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

here's my problem:

Table1: Posts

```
id - int
title - varchar
```

Table2: Categories

```
id - int
name - varchar
```

HABTM JoinTable: categories_posts

```
id - int
post_id - int
category_id - int
postorder - int
```

As you can see, the join table contains a field called 'postorder' - This is for ordering the posts in a particular category. For example,

```
Posts: Post1, Post2, Post3, Post4
Categories: Cat1, Cat2
Ordering:
     Cat1 - Post1, Post3, Post2
     Cat2 - Post3, Post1, Post4
```

Now in CakePHP,

```
$postpages = $this->Post->Category->find('all');
```

gives me a array like

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
      [Category] => Array
        (
          [id] => 13
          [name] => Cat1
        )
        [Post] => Array
        (
          [0] => Array
          (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => Post2
            [CategoriesPost] => Array
            (
              [id] => 17
              [post_id] => 1
              [category_id] => 13
              [postorder] => 3
            )
          )
          [1] => Array
          (
            [id] => 4
            [title] => Post1
            [CategoriesPost] => Array
            (
              [id] => 21
              [post_id] => 4
              [category_id] => 13
              [postorder] => 1
            )
          )

        )
    )
)
```

As you can see [Post], they are not ordered according to [CategoriesPost].postorder but are ordered according to [CategoriesPost].id. How can I get the array ordered according to [CategoriesPost].postorder?

Thanks in advance for your time :)

Update 1:
The Queries from Cake's SQL Log are:

```
SELECT `Category`.`id`, `Category`.`name` FROM `categories` AS `Category` WHERE 1 = 1

SELECT `Post`.`id`, `Post`.`title`, `CategoriesPost`.`id`, `CategoriesPost`.`post_id`, `CategoriesPost`.`category_id`, `CategoriesPost`.`postorder` FROM `posts` AS `Post` JOIN `categories_posts` AS `CategoriesPost` ON (`CategoriesPost`.`category_id` IN (13, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52) AND `CategoriesPost`.`post_id` = `Post`.`id`)
```

What I am looking for is how to make cake put a Order By CategoriesPost.postorder in that second SELECT SQL Query.

Update 2:
Trying to use order as following

```
$this->Post->Category->find('all',array('order'=>array('postorder'=>'ASC')));
```

throws an SQL error

```
SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'PostsCategory.postorder' in 'order clause'
```

The SQL Query is

```
SELECT `Category`.`id`, `Category`.`name` FROM `categories` AS `Category` WHERE 1 = 1 ORDER BY `CategoriesPost`.`postorder` ASC
```

Instead of an ORDERBY in the second SQL query (in my update1), its getting executed in the first SQL query as shown above.

Comment: It's been a while since I caked it up. If you throw in 'order'=>'CategoriesPost.postorder' is it ignored? I think I remember running into this at some point and having to use usort.

Comment: $this->Post->Category->find('all',array('order'=>array('CategoriesPost.postorder'=>'ASC'))) throws SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'PostsSitepage.postorder' in 'order clause'...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to make it part of the association:

```
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Post' => array(
        ...
        'order' => 'CategoriesPost.postorder DESC',
    )
)
```

This may or may not work, haven't tested it.

Comment: @Ashok,I'm sure this works.Just check the code of your `Category` model:)

Comment: Hey, this works! What happened was that the Categories and Posts models were in two different plugins and I didn't follow Plugin.Model notation. When I rectified it, the ordering started to work! Thank you everyone for your time :)